# pug ошибка при выводе из списка

Tags: pug

При выводе данных из списка выдает ошибку

**Код:**

```
var peopleList = [
  { 
    name: "Свами Даши", 
    photoLink: "img/people/dashi.jpg", 
    recource: "Свами Даши поможет вам снять порчу, снять порчу на семью, снять порчу на здоровье. У вас проблемы с детьми? вы думаете у вас порча? Свами Даши поможет снять порчу на одиночество, снять порчу на безбрачие. «Мы рядом. Мы поможем», - Свами Даши."
  {
    name: "Александр Шепс",
    photoLink: "img/people/sheps.jpg",
    recource: "Не идет бизнес? Думаете конкуренты навели порчу? Александр Шепс один из лучших экстрасенсов по данной проблеме. Он поможет снять порчу на деньги, снять порчу на бизнес, снять порчу на карьеру. Вы не один. Мы рядом."
  },
  {
    name: "Джулия Ванг",
    photoLink: "img/people/vang.jpg",
    recource: "У вас проблемы с детьми? Начали часто болеть? Дети плохо учаться в школе? Думаете дурное влияние? Джулия Ванг поможет снять порчу с детей, поможет снять порчу на будущее, поможет снять порчу на учебу, поможет снять порчу зависти. Дети - нашей будущее. Мы поможем."
  },
  {
    name: "Татьяна Ларина",
    photoLink: "img/people/larina.jpg",
    recource: "Вы потеряли смысл жизни? Вешаются руки? Уныние и депрессия не проходят? Татьяна Ларина поможет снять порчу на смерть, поможет снять порчу на усыхание, поможет вновь ощутить прилив жизни и найти смысл. Татьяна Ларина восстановит вашу энергетику, поможет снять порчу некротики, поможет снять порчу невезения. Вы обретете себя. Мы рядом."
  },
  {
    name: "Виктория Райдос",
    photoLink: "img/people/raidos.jpg",
    recource: "От Вас ушел муж? жена? чувствуете, что рушиться семья? Боритесь вместе с Викторией Райдос. Виктория поможет снять порчу на разруху семьи, поможет снять порчу на развал семьи, поможет пережить это горе, собраться с силами. Райдос поможет Вам снять порчу на одиночество, поможет снять порчу на безбрачие. Не унывайте. Все еще у вас впереди!"
  },
  {
    name: "Мерилин Керро",
    photoLink: "img/people/keppo.jpg",
    recource: "Проблемы с беременностью? Лежите на сохранении? Хотите внуков и детей? Проблемы по энергетике? Мерилин Керро одна из лучших знахарок и ворожек. Просмотрит и, главное, поможет снять порчу биополя, поможет снять порчу энергетики. Поможет обрести радость и счастье, поможет снять порчу бесплодия и самое ужасное перестанет быть проблемой. Мерилин Керро поможет снять порчу на искоренение рода. Мы не оставим Вас."
  },
  {
    name: "Наталья Бантеева",
    photoLink: "img/people/banteeva.jpg",
    recource: "Наталья Бантеева - ведущий специалист по коррекции судьбы. Потеряли работу? Ищите себя? Вас не ценят? Не берегут? Наталья Бантеева не пройдет мимо. Наталья Бантеева поможет снять порчу жизненного пути, поможет снять порчу судьбы. Дамоклов меч над вами? Наталье Бантеева снимет порчу! Верьте и будет дано."
  },
  {
    name: "Елена Ясевич",
    photoLink: "img/people/yasevich.jpg",
    recource: "Одиночество, старость, холодная постель. Вы на правильном пути, обратившись к Елене Ясевич. Снять порчу на одиночество, снять порчу на страх, снять порчу на негатив, снять порчу на фотографии, снять порчу - это первый шаг к победе. Победи свою судьбу. Сделай верный шаг."
  },
  {
    name: "Дарья Воскобоева",
    photoLink: "img/people/voskobaeva.jpg",
    recource: "Колдовство и проклятия, черная магия, привороты и сглазы - все это разрушает вашу жизнь. Дарья Воскобоева со знанием дела глубоко вникая в корень зла, снимет родовую порчу, поможет снять оковы зла и неправды, поможет снять чары. Останови разрушение твоей жизни."
  },
  {
    name: "Александр Литвин",
    photoLink: "img/people/litvin.jpg",
    recource: "Снять порчу на здоровье, восстановить силы, снять порчу на чакры, открыть каналы космоса, изменить жизнь. Александр Литвин - тот кто вам надо. Один из ведущих специалистов, профессионал. Александр поможет вам снять порчу на любовь, снять порчу на богатство и многое другое. Верьте и достигнете. А звезды мы повернем."
  },
  {
    name: "Елена Голунова",
    photoLink: "img/people/golunova.jpg",
    recource: "Дар проявился у Елены ещё в детстве. Находясь в пустой закрытой квартире, она увидела незнакомую женщину, которая при приходе родителей прошла их насквозь. Спустя некоторое время Елена Голунова поняла, что может не только видеть, но и слышать мертвецов. С умершими ей было комфортнее, так как с живыми она ощущала себя забытой и ненужной: родители обзавелись новыми семьями, забыв про дочь. Елену Голунову воспитывала бабушка, которая и стала раскрывать школьнице тайны новообретенных способностей, от которых отказалась мама."
  },
  {
    name: "Лилия Хегай",
    photoLink: "img/people/hegai.jpg",
    recource: "Лилия Хегай, полукореянка, полукитаянка по национальности, родилась 4 июля 1965 года в таджикском городе-курорте Оби-Гарм, где в то время работали ее родители. Большую часть своей жизни Лилия Хегай прожила в другой азиатской республике, в Узбекистане. Необычные способности Лилии стали проявляться в детстве. Но в полной мере дар проявился после клинической смерти, перенесенной в результате тяжелой болезни. Сама Лилия Хегай считает, что дар перешел ей в наследство от бабушки."
  },
  {
    name: "Мехди Эбрагими",
    photoLink: "img/people/ebragim.jpg",
    recource: "Колдовство и проклятия, черная магия, привороты и сглазы - все это разрушает вашу жизнь. Дарья Воскобоева со знанием дела глубоко вникая в корень зла, снимет родовую порчу, поможет снять оковы зла и неправды, поможет снять чары. Останови разрушение твоей жизни."
  },
  {
    name: "Зулия Раджабова",
    photoLink: "img/people/radjabova.jpg",
    recource: "Зулия Раджабова, известная поклонникам шоу «Битва экстрасенсам» как Зулия Раджабова – провидица в девятом поколении, обладает уникальным даром. Ее экстрасенсорные способности – «наследство» от старинного рода целителей Кавказа. Ясновидящая получила благословение в Египте. Зулия Раждабова родилась в Дагестане. Как и у многих экстрасенсов, у Зулии Раджабовой дар проявился в детстве, в 9 лет, после того, как она начала резко терять зрение."
  },
  {
    name: "Пахом Лучший",
    photoLink: "img/people/luchschui.jpg",
    recource: "Он сам себя называет юродивым и сумасшедшим. Ведет себя странно, странно разговаривает, неожиданно может впасть в состояние транса. Но у всех отпадают все сомнения как только вы видите Сергея в деле. Он талантливый экстрасенс и целитель."
  },
  {
    name: "Наталья Воротникова",
    photoLink: "img/people/vorotnikova.jpg",
    recource: "Наталья Юрьевна Воротникова родилась 10 апреля 1976 года в Тульской области. В первые младенческие дни своей жизни Наталья пережила две клинические смерти. При рождении у нее была диагностирована 4 степень асфиксии, ребенок был дважды обмотан пуповиной. С детства Наталья могла предчувствовать несчастья и трагические события. Наталью Воротникову еще ребенком называли ведьмой, спустя время стали называть девочка – радар."
  }
];

mixin people-card(people)
  div.people-card
    div.name
      h4= people.name
    div.photo= people.photoLink
    div.recource= people.recource

for people in peopleList
  +people-card(people)
```

**Ошибка:**

```
    1| var peopleList = [
  > 2|   {
---------^
    3|     name: 'Свами Даши',
    4|     photoLink: "img/people/dashi.jpg",
    5|     recource: "Свами Даши поможет вам снять порчу, снять порчу на семью, снять порчу на здоровье. У вас проблемы с детьми? вы думаете у вас порча? Свами Даши поможет снять порчу на одиночество, снять порчу на безбрачие. «Мы рядом. Мы поможем», - Свами Даши." },

unexpected text "{
  "
    at makeError (F:\GitHub\Psychics-of-Russia\node_modules\pug-error\index.js:32:13)
    at Lexer.error (F:\GitHub\Psychics-of-Russia\node_modules\pug-lexer\index.js:58:15)
    at Lexer.fail (F:\GitHub\Psychics-of-Russia\node_modules\pug-lexer\index.js:1304:10)
    at Lexer.advance (F:\GitHub\Psychics-of-Russia\node_modules\pug-lexer\index.js:1364:15)
    at Lexer.callLexerFunction (F:\GitHub\Psychics-of-Russia\node_modules\pug-lexer\index.js:1319:23)
    at Lexer.getTokens (F:\GitHub\Psychics-of-Russia\node_modules\pug-lexer\index.js:1375:12)
    at lex (F:\GitHub\Psychics-of-Russia\node_modules\pug-lexer\index.js:12:42)
    at Object.lex (F:\GitHub\Psychics-of-Russia\node_modules\pug\lib\index.js:99:27)
    at Function.loadString [as string] (F:\GitHub\Psychics-of-Russia\node_modules\pug-load\index.js:44:24)
    at F:\GitHub\Psychics-of-Russia\node_modules\pug-load\index.js:31:27
    at walkAST (F:\GitHub\Psychics-of-Russia\node_modules\pug-walk\index.js:23:18)
    at F:\GitHub\Psychics-of-Russia\node_modules\pug-walk\index.js:104:20
    at Array.reduce (native)
    at walkAndMergeNodes (F:\GitHub\Psychics-of-Russia\node_modules\pug-walk\index.js:103:18)
    at walkAST (F:\GitHub\Psychics-of-Russia\node_modules\pug-walk\index.js:37:19)
    at F:\GitHub\Psychics-of-Russia\node_modules\pug-walk\index.js:104:20
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

pug/jade чувствителен к пробелам, переносам строк, поэтому стоит их убрать:

```
-var peopleList = [ {  name: "Свами Даши", photoLink: "img/people/dashi.jpg",  recource: "Свами Даши поможет вам снять порчу, снять порчу на семью, снять порчу на здоровье. У вас проблемы с детьми? вы думаете у вас порча? Свами Даши поможет снять порчу на одиночество, снять порчу на безбрачие. «Мы рядом. Мы поможем», - Свами Даши." }, { name: "Александр Шепс", photoLink: "img/people/sheps.jpg", recource: "Не идет бизнес? Думаете конкуренты навели порчу? Александр Шепс один из лучших экстрасенсов по данной проблеме. Он поможет снять порчу на деньги, снять порчу на бизнес, снять порчу на карьеру. Вы не один. Мы рядом." } ];

mixin people-card(people)
  div.people-card
    div.name
      h4= people.name
    div.photo= people.photoLink
    div.recource= people.recource

for people in peopleList
  +people-card(people)
```

[Пример на codepen](https://codepen.io/semenchenko/pen/QMYKWV?editors=1000) там же увидеть и скомпилированный код.